# Next step after ANCOVA assumptions violation

Tags: regression, ancova

I'm analyzing the heart rate response of a sample of individuals to three tasks. Each individual performed all three tasks

I was recommended to do an ANCOVA with time to complete task as a covariate as the the time could impact an individual's response.

I tend to use Field's Discovering Statistics which recommends running an ANOVA between the covariate (time) and independent variables (tasks) to ensure they are independent

The output of this ANOVA is

|  | Df | Sum Sq | Mean Sq | F value | Pr(>F) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| event | 2 | 20501 | 10251 | 6.529 | 0.00259 |
| Residuals | 66 | 103617 | 1570 | ** |  |

which is significant and suggests the ANCOVA should not be run. The text seems to suggest using a multi-level generalised linear model to analyse this data (as it is repeated measures) but I wanted to see if anyone had any recommendations on appropriate analysis.

Thank you in advance